# Invoking method inside event handler is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-class

The `handleButtonPress` function works in the following example when no parameters are required...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {message:"HELLO"}
    this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this)
    this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleButtonPress}>
          <Text>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  handleButtonPress(){
    console.log("BUTTON WAS PRESSED")
    this.myFunc()
  }

  myFunc(){
    console.log("MY FUNCTION WAS CALLED")
    this.setState({message:"GOODBYE"})
  }

}
```

but doesn't work in the following example when parameters are required:

```
render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={function(){ this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE") }}>
          <Text>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  handleButtonPress(message){
    console.log("BUTTON WAS PRESSED WITH MESSAGE: " + message)
    this.myFunc(message)
  }

  myFunc(message){
    console.log("MY FUNCTION WAS CALLED")
    this.setState({message:message})
  }
```

It throws: `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE")')`

One strategy I've been using is to reference the `handleButtonPress` function again inside the `render` function, like this:

```
render(){
    handlePress = this.handleButtonPress;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={function(){ handlePress("GOODBYE") }}>
          <Text>Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

but is there another/better way?

Comment: `this` inside the anonymous function messed it up.

Comment: if you're saying it should be: `onPress={function(){ handleButtonPress("GOODBYE") }}`... that throws: `Can't find variable: handleButtonPress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's an anonymous function, the `this` context inside is the global `window` object. Since there is no `handleButtonPress` present, it throws the error that `undefined` is not a function. Your workaround works because `this` still refers to the class outside the anonymous function, thus allowing you to assign it's reference to  `handlePress` and call it.

To combat this, you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which will supplement a `this` context to the function. From the documentation linked:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value...

You can apply it here like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={function() { this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE") }.bind(this)}>
```

This will set the `this` context of the anonymous function to the class, instead of the global `window` object, thus allowing you to call `this.handleButtonPress`. The above can then be condensed again as mentioned by the documentation:

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, **with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.** (emphasis mine)
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

Where `arg1, arg2` etc are optional arguments of `bind` that can be bound to the function. This can be applied like so:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleButtonPress.bind(this, "GOODBYE")}>
```

This completely gets rid of the anonymous function, but `this` still must be passed in `bind` as you use it in your `handleButtonPress` method.

Comment: `onPress={function(){ this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE").bind(this) }}` throws the same error as without the bind: `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE")')` OOOH you're saying it should be `onPress={function(){ this.handleButtonPress("GOODBYE") }.bind(this) }`? yea that works. thanks!

Comment: @s2t2 No problem, glad to help :)